# Silverlight 4.0: HyperlinkButton

Tags: silverlight-4.0, hyperlink, isolatedstoragefile

How to redirect your navigateuri of hyperlinkbutton to your isolatedstorage?

or

Is there a workaround to display data from isolatedstorage to new browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont.

IsolatedStoratge is usable only by the API. You can no redirect the navigateurl to it.